# Mount encrypted home after ssh login permanently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, ssh, ecryptfs

I have set up an Ubuntu Server 14.04 with an encrypted home directory. The ssh public keys are outside the home directory so I can login after a restart, when the home directory is unmounted.

**I use `ecryptfs-mount-private` to mount the directory but after I logout, the directory seems to get unmounted again. How can I keep it mounted?**

I noticed, that when I login via VNC once after a restart and logout afterwards, the home directory stays mounted!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if following file exists on your system `~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount`.

Thats just an empty indicator file for enabling the auto-unmounting

Comment: Found it, renamed it and it works. Also I created a .profile in the unmounted home directory to get a prompt on login for mounting after a server restart. One more question though: Why didnt it unmount on logout over VNC ?

Comment: you saved my day ! ty